# How can duplicate the request in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Suppose i have this code

```
class SnippetList(APIView):
    """
    List all snippets, or create a new snippet.
    """
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        snippets = Snippet.objects.all()
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippets, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Now Let us suppose that in my get, i need to modify request.data

```
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        data = modify(request.data)
        request.data = data    # This don't work as i can't set attribute on request
        response = self.post(self, new_request, format=None)  # i want to do post method now with new request
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippets, many=True)
```

Is there any way to do that

Comment: Its really not clear what you are trying to do. Can you give a more coherent use case? Its likely there is a way to do what you want, but its not clear exactly what it is you want.

Comment: if you want to reuse code, then better put the common functionality in mixin and derive both calls from this mixin.

Comment: @eran i agree with that but then i need a separate endpoint for that which i can't do . i have only one endpoint avaialable and depending upon some request parameters i have to do POST in GET

Comment: @JohnKaff, but if everything is in the same class, just pull the functionality to third method.

Comment: @eran Actually i am not getting it . Can you give some example.

Comment: Your post is doing something. Its input is the int the data? so just write function which gets as input the data and call it once from the post and once from the get.

Comment: @eran  now i got it what your are saying . but i want to do that for many methods .current i have four m methods like GET , PUT, DELETE, POST .which looks clear. Then i have to make 4 more methods to abstract the functionality . Is there any other way just to have modified request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
def get(self, request, format=None):
        response = self.post(self, request, format=None, data=data )  # i want to do post method now with new request
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippets, many=True)
```

Now your method post should be:

```
def post(self, request, format=None, **kwargs):
        original_data = request.data
        additional_data = kwargs.get('data') # now you will be able to do whatever you want
        # more code goes here
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not modify your data upon get as they are usually marked as "unsafe" because they modify the data state.

You don't want to mess with the provided request either. It often creates more issues than it solves and adds some magic.

If you want the serializer to have more data than the request sent you should pass them to the serializer's save function. They will be added to the validated_data and available in the serializer's create / update methods (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#passing-additional-attributes-to-save)